# How to make the icon and text float to the left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am aiming to use Bootstrap's list group to create a navigation bar like this:

[image]

I'm wondering how I can move them to the left. Here's what I've tried.

```css
.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-group-item a {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="../home.html" class="list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Home</a>
  <a href="../explore/index.css" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i>Explore</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>Notifications</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>Messages</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmarks</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>Lists</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>More</a>
</div>
```

**Update**

I tried setting the min-width of the icons, but it doesn't work on my end because I realize I didn't demonstrate the whole problem well... This list-group is in a column of my grid. I am sorry!

Following is my full code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Explore</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Left column -->
      <div class="col">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="../home.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Home</a>
          <a href="../explore/index.css" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i>Explore</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>Notifications</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>Messages</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmarks</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>Lists</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i
                            class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Center column -->
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <!-- Right column -->
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply give the icons a minimum width so they're all the same, and align them to center. Then the text stacks nicely.

Flexbox doesn't really work because it's one-dimensional. It doesn't facilitate alignment between rows.

```css
.list-group-item i {
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="../home.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>Home</a>
  <a href="../explore/index.css" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-hashtag"></i>Explore</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>Notifications</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>Messages</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmarks</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>Lists</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I realized I didn't demonstrate my question fully so I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want align the navbar to left in the `col` as per your code. If so, here is the solution

```css
.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-group-item i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Explore</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Left column -->
      <div class="col">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fab fa-twitter mr-2"></i>Twitter</a>
          <a href="../home.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-house mr-2"></i>Home</a>
          <a href="../explore/index.css" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active d-flex align-items-center" aria-current="true"><i class="fas fa-hashtag mr-2"></i>Explore</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-bell mr-2"></i>Notifications</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>Messages</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-bookmark mr-2"></i>Bookmarks</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-list mr-2"></i>Lists</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i>Profile</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center"><i
                            class="fas fa-circle-minus mr-2"></i>More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Center column -->
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
      <!-- Right column -->
      <div class="col">
        Column
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```